# Capture part of name so that I can loop in linux

Tags: linux, bash

how do i capture a pattern in a filename and use that to do in linux?

example in a folder contains these files:
`BBB137O19_rc.fa
BBB921N08_cleaned.fa
BBB002O19_cc.fa`

I would like to capture the front part of the filename and use that to do things like renaming, run a program etc. Apparently, basename is greedy and works for everything before the extension.

thanks in advance

I tried this command but failed
`for i in *.fa; base=$(basename $i _*.fa); comb="${base}_ec.txt"; mv ec.txt $comb; done`

Comment: what exactly would the "front part" be for the given examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BASH string manipulations:

```
s='BBB921N08_cleaned.fa'

echo "${s%%_*}"
BBB921N08
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, sed can be used:
`echo "$i"|sed 's/_.*//'`

This removes `_` and any character (`.`) occuring any number of times after it (`*`). 
Sed with its regular expressions is especially useful, if you have more complicated patterns to process.